# How do I completely renew previous values of an input form in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on("click", ".searchbutton", function(e){
          var city = $("#searchbar").val()
          event.preventDefault();
          setInterval(function(){
                    var hdate = new Date()
                    var offset = 0 - hdate.getTimezoneOffset()/60
                    var hmin = hdate.getMinutes()
                    var hsec = hdate.getSeconds()
                    var diff = Math.round(Long/15) - offset
                    if((hdate.getHours() + diff) > 23){
                      disphour = (hdate.getHours() + diff) - 24
                      var formattedNumberh = ("0" + disphour).slice(-2)
                      $("#hour").text(formattedNumberh)
                    }
                    else if((hdate.getHours() + diff) < 0){
                      disphour = 24 + (hdate.getHours() + diff)
                      var formattedNumberh = ("0" + disphour).slice(-2)
                      $("#hour").text(formattedNumberh)
                    }
                    else{
                      disphour = hdate.getHours() + diff
                      var formattedNumberh = ("0" + disphour).slice(-2)
                      $("#hour").text(formattedNumberh)
                    }
                    var formattedNumberm = ("0" + hmin).slice(-2)
                    var formattedNumbers = ("0" + hsec).slice(-2)
                    $("#minute").text(formattedNumberm)                                    
                    $("#second").text(formattedNumbers)                                          
                }, 1000)   
})
```

This function is executed when a city name is put inside an input field and a button is pressed; it displays the time in that city.

When I put a city in the input field after refreshing the page, it works fine. However, when I put another city right after, the displayed hour fluctuates between the hour of the previous city and the new one.

I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: please provide html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never clear the interval.  So each "search" creates a new interval, and each interval keeps running and doing what it was told to do.

For example, you might track the "current interval" in a variable, and use that variable to clear the interval before creating a new one:

```
// track the interval
var currentInterval = -1;

$(document).on("click", ".searchbutton", function(e){
  // clear the current interval
  if (currentInterval > 0) {
    clearInterval(currentInterval);
  }

  var city = $("#searchbar").val();
  event.preventDefault();

  // set the new interval
  currentInterval = setInterval(function(){
    //...
  }, 1000);
});
```